# Yii2 SearchModel query - map integer values to strings

Tags: mysql, sql, yii2

What I am trying to achieve:

I have a table with a `type` field which holds integer values. These integer values represent different strings.

I want to be able to search the table using the string values that the integers represent.

E.g  `type = abc` rather than `type = 0`.

What have I tried:

I have created a query class for the model and tried to make use of the `$boolean_map` property:

```
class ReportQuery extends FilterableQuery
{
    protected $filterable = [
        'type' => 'LIKE',
        'removed_the_rest'
    ];
    protected $boolean_map = ["type" => [ 'addacs' => 0, "arudd" => 1,]];

}
```

Then I have overridden the `find` method of the model to use the query class:

```
 public static function find()
 {
    $query = new ReportQuery(get_called_class());
    return $query;
 }
```

And in the search model I have:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Report::find();

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query
    ]);

    $this->load($params, '');

    if (!$this->validate()) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'type' => $this->type,  
    ]);


    $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type', $this->type]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

When searching by the string values I get an empty result. Searching by the integer values produces the data.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better for you to make filter on that column instead of searching by string. You can do it for string as follows.

```
$filter = [
    'example1' => 1,
    'example2' => 2,
    'example3' => 3,
];

$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'type', $this->filter[$this->type]);
```

or in this place

```
// grid filtering conditions
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'type' => $this->filter[$this->type],  
])
```

also you can make filter dropdown on column, and for dropdown of that filter you can pass this array and just do

```
$query->andFilterWhere([
    'type' => $this->type,  
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you create mapping mechanism in query object? Okay, you show integer type as a string in frontend of your application, but the query shouldn't have details of representation. You should map string type to integer type in your search model. For example:

```
class ReportSearchModel extends ReportModel
{

    public function mapType($value)
    {
        $items = [
            'addacs' => 0, 
            'arudd' => 1
        ];
        return array_key_exists($value, $items) ? $items[$value] : null;
    }

    public function search($params)
    {
        //another code
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'type' => $this->mapType($this->type),
        ])
        //another code
    }
}
```

The alternative way is using an [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html) instead of mapping.